# Работа с SharePoint проектами в VS на обычной машине

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, sharepoint

Как открыть, редактировать, создавать SharePoint проекты в Visual Studio не на сервере SharePoint? Так же хотелось бы публиковать проекты (нужны .wsp пакеты), 
дебажить удаленно. **Возможно ли такое нестандартное решение?**

Шарик не установлен, ОС - Win10. VisualStudio 2015. OfficeTools установлен

Текущая проблема - студия ругается (при открытии, при публикации):

> Тип или имя пространства имен "SharePoint" не существует в пространстве имен "Microsoft"

и так на все, что связано с шариком

Comment: Добавьте библиотеки в References. И всё отлично заработает.

Comment: Если используется SSOM, то не заработает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать CSOM (Client side object model), это обмотка веб-служб SharePoint, будет доступна отладка. Может это Вам пригодится в каких-то сценариях. Только не путайте с JSOM.
[Примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx) работы с CSOM с сайта MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае необходимо скопировать библиотеки `SharePoint` недостающие в `References` проекта и добавить их вручную.

Это даст вам возможность сборки и публикации проекта, однако возможности отладить этот проект не будет.

Comment: Если библиотек под рукой нет, то можете взять из NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePoint/